# Javascript why does this function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects

Take a look into the below code and explain me why it returns `undefined` rather than the variable.

```js
function aaa() {
  return
  {
    test: 1
  };
}
console.log(aaa());
```

Comment: return is a statement. If nothing follows after it on the same line, it returns undefined

Comment: This will help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Automatic_Semicolon_Insertion

Comment: @JJJ I rolled back the edit but the question was marked as dupe at the same time. That caused the issue. Have again rolled back the edit.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I was not trying to fix anything. I improved an edit with fixing format of snippet. My intention was not fixing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you made a newline:

```js
function aaa() {
  return {
    test: 1
  };
}
console.log(aaa());
```

Comment: Just a pointer, for such questions, please look for a similar post and mark it as duplicate. Answering a duplicate is a bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

That's because of the new line at the end of `return` (Automatic Semicolon Insertion).

Try:

```
function aaa() {
  return {
     test: 1
  };
}
console.log(aaa());
```

Comment: Just a pointer, for such questions, please look for a similar post and mark it as duplicate. Answering a duplicate is a bad practice.

Comment: @Rajesh I couldn't find the original quesiton buddy or else i wouldn't have asked

Comment: @kannan Above comment was not for you. It was intended for CD.. Point was, the explanation for this question was easy and so people choose to answer instead of looking for duplicates. Which is wrong. If you know the solution, it more likely that you can phrase the search query better to find appropriate duplicate.